# Cauchy–Riemann equation on differntiability

Tags: derivatives

[image]

I have found that:

$U_x = -\exp(y)\sin(x) $

$U_y = \exp(y)\cos(x) $

$V_x = \exp(y)\cos(x) $

$V_y = \exp(y)\sin(x) $

I need to show that $U_x=V_y$ and $U_y=-V_x$, however these aren't satisfied? does that mean $f$ is not differentiable?

Answer (score 1):

Correct.  If the same expression that appears on the right side were $f(y+ix)$ rather than $f(x+iy)$ then it would be differentiable.

Comment: hypothetically in this case if we could set $x$ or $y$ to be such that both equations were satisfied then am I right to assume it will be differentiable at those points